# Launching a script when someone opens a file through the gui

Tags: scripts

I'm not even sure if this is possible or not but this is what I'm trying to do: Everytime a user opens a file through double clicking I want to launch a script which does a few things depending upon what kinda file it is or what directory it's in. How do I launch a script when the user opens a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible to do.

You will need to watch the file system using [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) to check for events (such as files being opened) and then handle them as required (such as running a shell script).

You will need to know about [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) too.

There are some examples on [the incron site](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=doc&lang=en), something like this may be a starting point for you:

> Example: You need to run program `abc` with the full file path as an
>   argument every time a file is changed in `/var/mail`. One of the
>   solutions follows:
>
> `/var/mail IN_CLOSE_WRITE abc $@/$#`

Comment: rtn: Have a read up and if you get stuck on specifics post a new question.

Comment: cool... looks promising. I'll give it a shot. Thanks